# CKEditor and Code parsing - strange change after submitting "<?" code

Tags: ckeditor

If I try, to write `"<?"` code into my CKEditor, it will be transformed into

```
<p>&lt;? lol</p>
```

It's OK. But if I submit my form and page is reloaded I will see:

```
<p><!--? lol</p--></p>
```

Any idea?

**EDIT**

Changed data are after page with form is reloaded with new submitted data.

The only one solution I tried is to instead "`<?`" write `@@` and in my template it replaces back to `<?`. I want it to write php codes as text in my articles. But this is not the best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I explained why does it happen in http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/11312

That's because your page does not encode content when outputting it to textarea.

This will work correctly:

```
<textarea class="ckeditor">
&lt;p&gt;&amp;lt;? lol&lt;/p&gt;
</textarea>
```

This will not:

```
<textarea class="ckeditor">
<p>&lt;? lol</p>
</textarea>
```

Because when CKEditor tries to read content from the second textarea it gets:

```
<p><? lol</p>
```

And that simply isn't correct HTML.

Your system has to replace every:

- `<` with `&lt;`
- `&` with `&amp;`
- `>` with `&gt;`

when printing textarea's HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Because that is proper HTML markup.

It is a named character reference
Named character references are often casually called entities

Details in [MDN HTML Intro](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Introduction#Named_character_references)

Comment: But there is problem -> i need to delete this parsing. Because if I want to use `<?` or `<?php` in Syntax Highlight plugin, it will be transformed to this strange code.